# PDO Insert into database values from dynamic html table

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, pdo

I'm new to PHP and have been struggling with a dynamic html table.  I have the table working, and I have been able to take those values and insert them into a table on my Mysql DB.  However to be honest, I'm confused as to why what I have works and why I can't get the method of using "bindValue" to work?

Can someone explain why the bindValue approach is not working?  Here is the code I have.  If you see something that could be improved upon I would be glad to hear your thoughts.

```
 <!-- This is from my HTML file -->

    <script language="javascript">

function addRow(tableID) { 

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "checkbox";
    element1.name="chkbox[]";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='itemdesc[]' >";

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='number'  name='unitprice[]' >";

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell4.innerHTML =  "<input type='number'  name='quantity[]' >";

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
    cell4.innerHTML =  "<input type='number'  name='linetotal[]' >";
    }

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
    }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

This is from my .php file

```
    for($i=0; $i < count($_POST['itemdesc']); $i++)
{


try
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO invoicelineitem SET
        invoiceid = " . $last_id .",
        itemdesc = '" . $_POST['itemdesc'][$i] ."',
        unitprice = " . $_POST['unitprice'][$i].",
        quantity = " . $_POST['quantity'][$i].",
        linetotal = " . $_POST['linetotal'][$i];
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->execute();

/* I can't get this to work

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO invoicelineitem SET
        invoiceid = :invoiceid,
        itemdesc = :itemdesc,
        unitprice = :unitprice,
        quantity = :quantity,
        linetotal = :linetotal';
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':invoiceid', $last_id);
    $s->bindValue(':quantity', $_POST['quantity'][$i]);
    $s->bindValue(':untiprice', $_POST['unitprice'][$i]);
    $s->bindValue(':itemdesc', $_POST['itemdesc'][$i]);
    $s->bindValue(':linetotal', $_POST['linetotal'][$i]);
    $s->execute();
 */
```

This is the error message I get:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in /media/sf_mcpi/mcpi/invoice/index.php:216 Stack trace: #0 /media/sf_mcpi/mcpi/invoice/index.php(216): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}

Comment: Is this a typo `:unitprice,d` <= the `d` and quote in `linetotal'` <= Using exceptions would have caught those errors. `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`

Comment: You appear to be mixing PHP and JavaScript and that will not work.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Good catch ;-) I didn't see that till you mentioned it.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo that happened when posting my code.  The JavaScript and HTML are in a separate file from my PHP code.  I added comments to reflect this.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Also `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: Here is the error I'm getting.   exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in /media/sf_mcpi/mcpi/invoice/index.php:216 Stack trace: #0 /media/sf_mcpi/mcpi/invoice/index.php(216): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}

Comment: untiprice insted of unitprice, the placeholder and the bindparam value are different

Comment: @Mihai Another good catch.

Comment: For crying out loud!!!!  Great catch.  Yep, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is setup as if it were an `UPDATE` query. An `INSERT` query is different, using this format:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`col1`, `col2`, ...)
VALUES ('val1', 'val2', ...)
```

An `INSERT` requires that you specify the columns you'll be inserting into followed by an equal number of `VALUES`.

UPDATE: Thanks to the good catch by @Mihai, "untiprice insted of unitprice, the placeholder and the bindparam value are different"

Comment: *Hm...* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html says `INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)]
    SET col_name={expr | DEFAULT}, ...` so it's hard to say really. I thought of that also. Let's see what OP has to say ;-)

Comment: *Hmmmmm*, I see your point @Fred-ii- though it seems a fairly non-standard way of performing inserts.

Comment: I know Jay. You stand at being 50% right ;-) I've posted a comment under OP's question about checking for errors, see what pans out.

Comment: Roger that @Fred-ii- ;-)

Comment: Am wondering if OP should be using `bindParam` rather than `bindValue`.

Comment: Not sure how much difference that would make in this case @Fred-ii-

Comment: Not entirely sure myself. OP hasn't come back with anything yet, in regards to comments left anywhere. But there are differences between both.

Comment: [...and now we know](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306624/pdo-insert-into-database-values-from-dynamic-html-table#comment44965756_28306624)

Comment: Yes we do @Fred-ii- ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I think we owe [credit to Mihai](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306624/pdo-insert-into-database-values-from-dynamic-html-table#comment44966219_28306624) also. A mention and *Kudos to* would set the record straight ;-)

Comment: Done dealio @Fred-ii-

Comment: Glad this one was finally solved. Cheers to all who've helped. ;-)

Comment: Oh come on,I dont really need to see my name in the credits of the great movie "Catch the typo"

Comment: @Mihai That was my idea. I think it's good to mention it. However, if you feel strongly about it, ask Jay to remove it. I myself always give credit where credit is due.